# How to remove strikethrough from label once click on legend

Tags: javascript, chart.js, legend

How to remove strikethrough from label once clicked on legend and show only label text

Comment: I am using ChartJS

Comment: can you show the code so far?

Comment: For example (I want to remove the strike on click of legend ): http://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/WGZGNE

Comment: Any update? I am also trying to remove strike on text.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this by using **labelformatter**

```
{
  
  "xAxis": {
     "categories": ["abcd", "efgh"],
    
  },
  
  "legend": {
        enabled: true,
        symbolRadius: 2,
        margin: 0,
        itemHoverStyle: {
            color: '#000'
        }, itemHiddenStyle: {
            color: '#cccccc' 
        },
        labelFormatter: function () { 
            return `<div><div style=" height:18px; width: 18px; border-radius: 2px;"></div><div style="display:inline-block;margin:0px 0px 0px 20px;font-size:small;">${this.name}</div></div>`;
        }
    },
  
  "series": [{
  "minPointLength": 3,
    "type": "column",
    "pointPlacement": 0.2,
    "name": "Series1",
    "turboThreshold": 4,
    "data": [{
      "name": "abcd",
      "y": 12765433.5
     
    }, {
      "name": "efgh",
      "y": 0
      
    }],
 
  }, {
    "minPointLength": 3,
    "type": "column",
    "pointPlacement": 0.2,
    "name": "Series2",
    "turboThreshold": 1,
    "data": [{
      "name": "abcd",
      "y": 15.2
    }],
 
  }]
}
```

Comment: Please format this using code tags

Comment: Added Thanks for the response

Comment: @possum  please refer the link for the solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/rajputshaily/srfu4q0b/4/